Annoying bug with Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible servers (v16.1) with "pg_read_all_data" role
I have been working on granting a read-only rights to a certain role within Postgres-flex v16, but that doesn't work. I login with my Azure admin account on the postgres-db server for creating a new role and granting some read-only permissions to it.
Please find the error which I receive, when I try to grant "pg_read_all_data" role to the newly created role:
postgres=> GRANT pg_read_all_data to kypdba;
ERROR:  permission denied to grant role "pg_read_all_data"
DETAIL:  Only roles with the ADMIN option on role "pg_read_all_data" may grant this role.


If I try to grant "pg_read_all_settings" role, that does work, but I am not interested in that role. Did Microsoft did it on purpose? Is there any documentation confirming that only the membership roles shown in the above output for the admin user will work, but not others like "pg_read_all_data"? I couldn't find anything about it online!
The same set of commands shown above work perfectly for v15 and v14 (I have checked on other Postgres Flex databases in Azure). What is further frustrating is that the admin role (blurred in \du command output shown above) gets added as a member of the newly created role with this command. Please find additional info about server as to how I connect via PSQL in terminal:
psql (15.6 (Homebrew), server 16.1)
WARNING: psql major version 15, server major version 16.
         Some psql features might not work.
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

Thanks in advance for your time, and for any help.
